# Crashing with 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional' on UISegmentedControl setTitle method

Tags: swift3, option-type, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a sourceViewController which is accessing a `UISegmentedControl` in destinationViewController. `EventType` is an enum defined as:

```
enum EventType: Int {
    case Rashifal, RashiGyan
}
```

The title of segmentedControl on destinationViewController should change according to the change of the value of segmentedControl on sourceViewController.

Whenever the segmentedControl is tapped in sourceViewController, value changed is seen, as I have printed in the console. Now, I want to change the content of `segmentedControl` in destinationViewController according to the previously selected `segmentedControl` value in my sourceViewController.

The value of `segmentedControl` in destinationViewController works fine on the first run and as expected, but when I navigate to my sourceViewController and change the segmentedControl and navigate to destinationViewController, there's a crash with message `Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` in a console.

Here's how I have tried to change the value of my segmentedControl in destinationViewController from sourceViewController.

```
 @IBAction func segmentedControlValueChanaged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    let eventType = EventType(rawValue: sender.selectedSegmentIndex)!

    let anotherVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Rashifal", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RashiDetailVC") as? RashiDetailVC
    switch eventType {
    case .Rashifal:
        print("at Rashifal")
        anotherVC?.segmentedControl.setTitle("दैनिक", forSegmentAt: 0)
        anotherVC?.segmentedControl.setTitle("साप्ताहिक", forSegmentAt: 1)
        anotherVC?.segmentedControl.setTitle("मासिक", forSegmentAt: 2)
        anotherVC?.segmentedControl.setTitle("वार्षिक", forSegmentAt: 3)
    case .RashiGyan:
        print("At RashiGyan")
        anotherVC?.segmentedControl.setTitle("विशेषता", forSegmentAt: 0)
        anotherVC?.segmentedControl.setTitle("शुभ/अशुभ", forSegmentAt: 1)
        anotherVC?.segmentedControl.setTitle("प्रेम", forSegmentAt: 2)
        anotherVC?.segmentedControl.setTitle("जीवन", forSegmentAt: 3)
    }

}
```

What might have possibly gone wrong?

Comment: Are you presenting RashiDetailVC with a segue in the storyboard?

Comment: It's a Storyboard segue of kind show.

Comment: This is because u have just got controller object and its properties are not initilized yet, they will initialized when viewDidload or viewwillappear method will call !! Thats whys segmentedControl object is nil
To remove it, why not u set these segment control value on controller viewDidload or viewwillappear method of controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass data to a VC that you are going to show, do not use the `instantiateViewController` method. That will give you a *new* VC, instead of the one that is going to be presented.

First, make a variable called `eventType` in the destination controller:

```
var eventType: EventType!
```

Override `prepareForSegue` in source VC:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // make segmentedControl as an IBOutlet if you haven't done already
    let eventType = EventType(rawValue: segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)!
    if let vc = segue.destination as? RashiDetailVC {
        vc.eventType = eventType
    }
}
```

In the destination VC's `viewDidLoad`, do the switch statement:

```
        switch eventType {
        case .Rashifal:
            print("at Rashifal")
            segmentedControl.setTitle("दैनिक", forSegmentAt: 0)
            segmentedControl.setTitle("साप्ताहिक", forSegmentAt: 1)
            segmentedControl.setTitle("मासिक", forSegmentAt: 2)
            segmentedControl.setTitle("वार्षिक", forSegmentAt: 3)
        case .RashiGyan:
            print("At RashiGyan")
            segmentedControl.setTitle("विशेषता", forSegmentAt: 0)
            segmentedControl.setTitle("शुभ/अशुभ", forSegmentAt: 1)
            segmentedControl.setTitle("प्रेम", forSegmentAt: 2)
            segmentedControl.setTitle("जीवन", forSegmentAt: 3)
        }
```

This ensures that the segmented control has been initialised before you set its title.

Comment: There's no crash but there' no value change as well in the destinationViewController segmentedControl now.